# How do I mock headers with connexion?

Tags: python, connexion

I am using connexion to read a few headers in my productive code, i.e.:

```py
from connexion import request

def get_my_header() -> str:
    return request.headers.get("my-header")
```

In the connexion docs I found the [TestContext](https://connexion.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.6/testing.html#testcontext).
This sounds quite promising, but I can't find any example on how I would mock headers, so that when testing `get_my_header()` the headers are set. I have tried many different ways on how to set this up. I found this promising, but it just won't work:

```py
from connexion.testing import TestContext

def test_get_my_header():
  request = MagicMock()
  request.headers = {"my-header": "header-value"}
  with TestContext(context={"request": request}):
    # test code
```

Any ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it.
The headers are set through the scope rather than the context.
`TestContext` even has a static method to build those:

```
from connexion.testing import TestContext

def test_get_my_header():
  with TestContext(
    scope=TestContext.build_scope(headers=[(b"my-header", b"header-value")])
  ):
    # test code
```